# Elliptical Polarization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

How can we say that the states $$|\psi _1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(-|h\rangle + \sqrt{2}\, e^{-i2\pi/3}|v\rangle),$$
$$|\psi _2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(-|h\rangle + \sqrt{2}\, e^{i2\pi/3}|v\rangle)$$ are elliptically polarized? $|h\rangle$ and $|v\rangle$ represent the horizontal and vertical polarization respectively.

Also, how can the elliptically polarized state be decomposed (mathematically) into two linearly polarized states with the planes of polarization perpendicular to each other?

Comment: 'how can the elliptically polarized state be decomposed' That is exactly what your expressions describe: linear combinations of linearly polarized fields.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see how? How can we write $|\psi _1\rangle $ as such a linear combination?

Comment: @devanshushekhar You have *already* written in such a linear combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can say they are ellipitcally polarised by elimination.

- Linear polarisation light means that $h$ and $v$ are either in phase or $\pi$ out of phase:
  $$ \mathbf{E} = [\cos(\omega t), \cos(\omega t +\pi)] $$
  [image]
- Circular polarisation light means that $h$ and $v$ are $\pi/2$ out of phase:
  $$ \mathbf{E} = [\cos(\omega t), \cos(\omega t +\pi/2)] $$
  [image]
- Your case would give this plot, so it's elliptical:

[image]

Technically the phase alone tells you the ellipticty of the polarisation if the amplitudes of the two components is the same. In your case they are not so that's another reason as to why it's elliptical.

Mine and your formuale are *already* in an orthogonal basis, $|h\rangle$ and $|v\rangle$, so they are already decomposed into two linearly polarised states with the planes of polarization perpendicular to each other.

Comment: 'they are already decomposed into two linearly polarised states', it is just a representation in the basis, isn't it? How about this: $|\psi \rangle = \frac{-1}{2}(|h \rangle + \sqrt {3} |v \rangle )$. This is not an elliptically polarized light.

Comment: The basis you are writing them in , $h$ and $v$, are linearly polarised. So you are already writing the state in terms of these two states, the projections in the latest case are $-1/2$ and $-\sqrt{3}/2$.